# How install pcnfs on Centos 7

Tags: centos, rpm, nfs

I have CentOS 7.2 on my NFS server, but I can't find the rpm for pcnfs. I have some DOS clients that use pcnfs authentication for mounting partitions. Due to an old netapp being removed, I need redirect mounts to a new server but can't pass authentication in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I found old release of  pcnfs on slackwere and downloaded it from mirror :  https://hkg.mirror.rackspace.com/slackware/slackware-10.2/pasture/pcnfsd-93.02.16-i486-1.tgz
after untar , it's create file /usr/sbin/rpc.pcnfsd that autorun by manual crate service :

```
     [Unit]
Description=pcnfsd Service 
Wants=nss-user-lookup.target
After=syslog.target network-online.target nfs-server.service

[Service]
Type=forking
NotifyAccess=all
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.pcnfsd
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2) crate **local** users (NIS users not work )

3) crate /etc/pcnfsd.conf i added to him

```
uidrange UID
```

4) start service
* dos clients pass authentication and connect successfully to NFS disc with user (2) permissions